# How to fix the color issue within two different pages in (android java) mobile app

Tags: android

I have created some frames successfully with a database connection but the issue is rising if I log in to the page then it will show the **Activity_main.xml** chat page then if I click a person in the page contact, then it's successfully going to another page is **chat details** page but if I click **backArrow** button then the main activity contact page has changed, color! but I don't set the color so I want the default yellow color, but I don't know why the color is changing and I checked many ways but I didn't find that error so please give me the solution if anyone knew!

I'm trying to go back through the `back arrow` button but the issue is if I click to come to the back page the color was changed, but I want the default color white at all times. I'll provide screenshots of my issue.

[activity_main.xml page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acNpz.png)
[activity_main.xml page after clicked back arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEvg9.png)
[activity_chat_details.xml page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAER5.png)

**themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ConnectProject" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/cn_colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>


    <color name="colorPrimary">#0b6156</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#095049</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
    <color name="lightGrey">#EDEDED</color>
    <color name="whatsAppColor">#0b6156</color>
    <color name="red">#9F0B0B</color>
    <color name="status_background">#009688</color>
    <color name="chat_background">#8BC34A</color>
    <color name="fb_color">#3c5793</color>
    <color name="lightgreen">#e5ffcc</color>
    <color name="settingsIconColor">#0E8374</color>
    <color name="grayBackground">#BCBCBC</color>
    <color name="chatbackground">#AAAAAA</color>

    <color name="cn_secondary_variant">#3C6382</color>
    <color name="cn_colorPrimary">#30336B</color>
    <color name="cn_background">#2F3542</color>
    <color name="cn_chat_bg">#C3E6FF</color>
    <color name="cn_primary_gray">#9A9A9A</color>

</resources>
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/cn_colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        app:tabIndicator="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        />





</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_chat_detail.xml page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChatDetailActivity"
    android:background="@color/cn_chat_background">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chatRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/linear">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/enterMessage"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_et_message"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your message.."
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/sendMsg"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            app:srcCompat = "@drawable/sendnew"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backkArrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.476"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/leftarrowwhite" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar3"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/backkArrow"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:text="Akthar Fravees"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/call" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/videocall" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/menudot" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```